# M0 COMMAND USING THALES PAYSHIELD 9000

Tags: hsm

I have  to send a M0 command  to  HSM  but  I  dont  know What  I should  send, somebody  gave  me  an example  that  they send

000003M0002100BU761D8715ACC89399D328AA0FA047BE820040543DDABC563D6EF4F944AD59C979CDD64158FEA07A7207C39F036B0B0633FC60
And  ready  a little  about  the  documentation I  found  the next

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge about HSM is little but anyway i try to help.
I access old simulation application that have some help for you.
Go to [thalessim](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=thalessim) and download source. Expand and find some file jason with " M0 ".
The file 429909.json has good information.
Others information:
M0 - Encrypt Data Bloc, replace for HE command, Encrypt Data
HSM to do the encryption by using the HE command which we have to pass in the Encrypted TAK.
HE command is to Encrypt a 64bit data block with a TAK. According to HSM vendor, it is an optional command and required additional license to using it.

Good luck.